# Jquery, multiple CSS properties in variables

Tags: jquery, css, variables

I would like to have, with Jquery, multiples **css** properties in **variables**. This code doesn't work :

```
var deco = {"text-decoration":"none"};
var bak = {"background-color":"cyan"};


$("a").css( deco , bak );
```

What is wrong in my code ? Thanks. Nicolas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong is that you're calling the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function in a way it's not written to be called. The version accepting an object just accepts a single object.

You can combine your objects as you pass them in with [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend):

```
$("a").css( $.extend( {}, deco , bak ) );
```

Example:

```js
console.log("And...");
setTimeout(function() {
  var deco = {"text-decoration":"none"};
  var bak = {"background-color":"cyan"};
  $("a").css( $.extend( {}, deco , bak ) );
  console.log("...done");
}, 800);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Testing 1 2 3</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: I'd strongly recommend using a class for that rather than inline styling, unless you have a strong, specific reason not to.

Comment: It works very well ! ...I use, of course, a style sheet for all my css rules, but here, this is for a really special case. Many Thanks for your help. Nicolas.